# Do I need to use an auxiliary verb?

Tags: questions, auxiliary-verbs

I have a sentence

**When tourists visit Australia?**

Now, my question is - do I need to put "do" in it?

**When do tourists visit Australia?**

I don't know why, but the first one seems more natural to me.
Thanks!

Comment: Yes, because interrogatives require subject-auxiliary inversion. If there is no auxiliary verb present in the basic order version, the dummy auxiliary verb "do" must be inserted before the subject.

Comment: As @BillJ says. As such, the first example by itself is not a question. For example, you could say "*When tourists visit Australia*, tour operators are happy and profitable."

Comment: It isn't particularly useful to answer a question with "Why?  That's just the way English is", particularly in the comments section where it can't be downvoted.  There is a reason here, as BillJ explains.  If you don't know that reason, you can let someone else explain.

Answer (score -1):

Your two sentences have two completely different meanings.

It depends what you are asking

> When tourists visit Australia?

might be used to ask if something happens **while** tourists are visiing Australia

> When do tourists visit Australia?

ask about the time and dates when tourists visit Australia.